# How can I pull remote directory first time?

Tags: git, github

I am asked to take clone of project repository from GitHub server.

There are three branches on server: `master`, `qa` and `dev`.

After taking clone to the project, how can I checkout `qa` or `dev` branch as both the branches are not on my local machine?

I tried the command

```
git checkout qa
```

it raised an error

> $ git checkout qa error: pathspec 'qa' did not match any file(s) known
>   to git.

Comment: I edited the question @Biffen

Comment: I know to switch a branch, --git checkout branchName, but this is when you have that branch on your local machine.

Comment: Did you try `git checkout qa`?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work

Comment: I don't know why it is downvoted? Is there some thing not clear? or question doesn't make sense anyway?

Comment: ‘*Doesn't work*’ will *not* help anyone solve your problem! *How* doesn't it work? What happens?

Comment: As for the downvote: Could it be the lack of information in the question? Preferably, it should have included *from the start*; the command used to clone, how you determined that the branches were *not* in your local repository, the commands you've tried to switch branch and *the output* thereof.

Comment: What is the basic knowledge about git commands, I ignored it to mention here, because anyone who knows a.b.c. of git, also knows how to 'clone'. And how I came to know that there are other branches on the server, I am not sitting in jungle, but in my office besides my colleagues. So I think it doesn't matter.

Comment: So everything's working, then? Great! If you have a question, you will have to supply some background.

Comment: Check the answers, they got the things, but you could not. Thank you very much.

Comment: Since `git clone`, `cd`, `git checkout` *ordinarily* work just fine, you must have done something out of the ordinary. Hence my asking for more information.

Answer (score 27):

Suppose your project is called SomeProject library and you need branches `qa` and `dev` besides default `master`. Here's what you do:

```
git clone https://github.com/someperson/someproject.git
cd someproject
git checkout -b qa origin/qa
git checkout -b dev origin/dev
```

Now your local branches `qa` and `dev` track corresponding remote branches, and you can check them out:

```
git checkout qa
git checkout dev
```

Comment: `git checkout qa` and `git checkout dev` should suffice.